# Text-processing Windows without additional software?

Tags: windows, text-processing, text-parsing

I've got these machine that output a lot of data. Unfortunately, the files outputted are structured in a strange way. I'd like to be able to do some complex text processing (perl style) to parse the data and be able to output to Excel format. I'd also like to automate this but the only server that I can use is running Windows XP (with Office) and I'm not allowed to install any extraneous software (no .NET, Powershell, ActivePerl, etc.) 
What is the best way to do this? Are regex in VB/VBA powerful enough for me to script in Excel?

Comment: If you compile a program in a language to a standalone exe than can you run that on the machine? Also, remember that regex is not the only solution. If it really is complex then it might be worth it to try and define the grammer and use a program like yacc to make a parser.

Comment: @Mat Yes, I can run an executable. I'll take a look at the grammar parsers, but I'd still need a way to import to excel.

Comment: @Mat And the files aren't really too complex. They're pretty much a bunch of whitespace-delimited multi-line entries, which is why I intended on using perl/regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/). It has an inbuilt regex engine and there is an excel standard include. It can compile to a standalone exe so fits the bill. It's also pretty simple as a langauge, so shouldn't take to long to figure out coming from other languages.

Comment: @Mat Nevermind, I don't think that will work. I'm pretty sure I can;t interact with the GUI in any way.

Comment: @Mat, I've just found out about Strawberry Perl Portable. I might give that a try.

Comment: @Bat Masterson, what makes you think you need to interact with the GUI? That's not what AutoIt does. I'd read a bit more and look at some file examples.

Comment: AutoIt is a great language for this. It can do regular expressions and has a great library for working with Excel. It also doesn't require installation in order to work and it doesn't rely on any huge frameworks like .NET. AutoIt is a general purpose language, by the way, not a purely GUI automation language although it does excel there.

Comment: @Manadar, Thanks! Can the AutoIT scripts be run without installing AutoIT?

EDIT: Nevermind, found this http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm

Comment: Yes, that's so great about it for this particular purpose. You can create very small executables which will run on a lot of different machines. AutoIt handles all the OS specific features transparently, most of the time.